# C# understanding of hostname and IPAddress of a printer

Tags: c#, printing, ip-address, host

```
 _Printers = new PrintServer().GetPrintQueues(new[] { 
     EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local, EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections});
```

The above code allows me to get a list of printers that available for me to print. One of the printer description is as below:

```
\\EYZR370\HP Color LaserJet 2605dn,HP Universal Printing PCL 6 (v5.1),
```

Now I'm trying to find the Ip Address of the printer manually using the following way:

1 -> Go to Control Panel

2-> View devices and printers

3-> Right-click on HP Color LaserJet 2605dn and select printer properties

4-> Select Port tab to see the IP Address

Now it shows the IPAddress for example `192.157.6.8`

**I'm wondering if 192.157.6.8 == EYZR370?**

So I try the following way:

```
string hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("192.157.6.8").HostName;
```

Suprisingly `hostName` is having another string value that I've no clue what is it about.

Can anyone actually explain what is it all about regarding my case?

**Updates:**

I've done another test using the following way

```
  IPHostEntry hostEntry;

  hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry("EYZR370");

  //you might get more than one ip for a hostname since 
  //DNS supports more than one record

  if (hostEntry.AddressList.Length > 0)
  {
      //var ip = hostEntry.AddressList[0];
  }
```

I can see there are 6 data for `hostEntry.AddressList` but none of them match `192.157.6.8`?

Answer (score 0):

`HostName` property returns the *primary* host name.

You might want to check out the `Aliases` property which returns the list of possible aliases.   If your machine has more than one DNS name which resolves to the `192.157.6.8`, then you'll find it in the aforementioned property.

You might also want to try similar (though obsolete) methods like `Dns.Resolve` and `Dns.GetHostByAddress`. Some people have reported these methods work differently.

Is the printer configured properly? It seems the printer doesn't have a host name or the DNS isn't configured properly? Or maybe you have the wrong name altogether? Do you have access to its web control panel?

Comment: Have you tried resolving `EYZR370` to an IP address?

Comment: Please take a look at my updated question to see if I use the correct way to find the IP Address